# Codeigniter cross domain session

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I,ve one question left about Codeigniter sessions. I have three domains:

- http://mijn.exova.nl/
- http://m4th2.nl/
- http://t-world.nl/

On the first domain users can login in the system. But they also van login for the last
two domains. So for the users we have one database for three systems.

So when an user log in on http://mijn.m4th.nl/ they are also logged in on for example
http://m4th2.nl/. On the localhost it worked perfectly. The three systems used the same 
session. I set the session encryption key for the three Codeigniter installations the same.

But when i install this systems on the three domains the session is not shared like the localhost. The domains are on the same server.

Does someone know how to solve this problem? I tried already to save the session in my user db. But when we connect both systems to that table the session is not shared.

Here are my settings for http://mijn.m4th.nl. The settings on the other systems are the same.

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
$config['cookie_prefix']    = "";
$config['cookie_domain']    = "";
$config['cookie_path']      = "/";
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
```

Thanks!

Comment: When you had it set up on local, were the three sites all using the same domain?

Comment: Yes, we set them op on http://localhost/

Comment: What a surprise... you can have same cookies only on same domain eg. subdomain.domain.com, subdomain2.domain.com (you set `$config['cookie_domain'] = '.domain.com';`, forget about your setup.

Comment: Hmm óke. It is not possible on multiple domains. So i have to copy the login two times for the other two systems.  
Unfortunate.  Thanks for the comments.